# Number of words in a string Infinite Loop

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this? I'm trying to get the program to return the number of words in the string. It is stuck in an infinite loop...

```
int NumberNames(String wholename)

{    
    String testname=wholename;

    int numnames=0;

     int posBlank= testname.indexOf(' ');

     while(testname.length()>0)
    {   
       testname = testname.trim();

       testname=testname.substring(posBlank+1,testname.length());

       numnames++;

       System.out.println(testname);
    }    

    return numnames;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues. You're not resetting the value of posBlank within your loop, and if you pass in a string without spaces, your substring always just returns the whole string. You'll need to solve both. Try this:

```
int NumberNames(String wholename)
{
    String testname=wholename;
    int numnames=1;
    int posBlank= testname.indexOf(' ');

    while(posBlank > 0)
    {   
       testname = testname.trim();
       testname=testname.substring(posBlank+1,testname.length());
       posBlank= testname.indexOf(' ');
       numnames++;
       System.out.println(testname);
    }    

    return numnames;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `wholeName.trim().split(" ").length` instead

Answer (score 2):

why not just use `String.split(\\s)` instead??

```
 String testname=wholename;
 String[] words = testname.split("\\s");
 sysout(words.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return wholename.length() - wholename.replace(" ", "").length() + 1
```

Comment: Although this doesn't actually take into consideration multiple blanks at a time... you could run a loop that replaces every two blank section with a one blank section until the length remains the same.